# Struts2 Using iterator tag for arraylist object field issues

Tags: struts2

I am working on a project where I load objects into an ArrayList arrayDiary in my action class populate method. The page linking to this page has the URL 'populateDiary.action'. I have public getters & setters for this arrayList and I can see that the populate method is called and the arrayList does actually contain values.

My problem is that when I try to populate a li using the STRUTS iterator tag I am not seeing anything on the screen. I have read several posts on this and as far as I can see have copied them exactly - however I am not seeing my results on the screen.
Heres my diary.jsp code:

```
<s:iterator value="arrayDiary" status="pos" id="res">
<li onclick="$('#eventList').toggleClass('eventList'); $('#eventDesc').toggleClass('eventDesc'); $('.active').toggleClass('active'); $(this).toggleClass('active');"><a href="#"><s:property value="#res.title"/></a></li>
</s:iterator>
```

Heres my action class code:

```
private ArrayList<DiaryEntry> arrayDiary;
private ArrayList<DiaryEntry> arrayEvent;

public String populate() {
    ArrayList<DiaryEntry> arrayEvent = new ArrayList<DiaryEntry>();
    ArrayList<DiaryEntry> arrayDiary = new ArrayList<DiaryEntry>();
    DiaryEntry load = new DiaryEntry();
    username = (String) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("username");
    loginId = (String) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("loginId");
    ArrayList<DiaryEntry> diaryEntry = load.loadDiaryEntry(username, loginId);
    for (DiaryEntry entry:diaryEntry) {
        if(entry.getEvent() == null) {
            arrayDiary.add(entry);
        }
        else {
            arrayEvent.add(entry);
        }
    }
    return "populate";
}

public ArrayList<DiaryEntry> getArrayDiary() {
    return arrayDiary;
}

public void setArrayDiary(ArrayList<DiaryEntry> arrayDiary) {
    this.arrayDiary = arrayDiary;
}

public ArrayList<DiaryEntry> getArrayEvent() {
    return arrayEvent;
}

public void setArrayEvent(ArrayList<DiaryEntry> arrayEvent) {
    this.arrayEvent = arrayEvent;
}
```

Heres my struts.xml:

```
<action name="*Diary" method="{1}" class="spirit.DiaryAction">
    <result name="populate">/diary.jsp</result>
    <result name="input">/diary.jsp</result>
    <result name="success">/diary.jsp</result>
</action>
```

I would really appreciate if someone can spot where i've gone wrong. I've been working on this issue for 2 days now with no success. Thanks in advance for your help and feedback.

Comment: Not really possible to diagnose from the info given, although `id` is deprecated for `var`. Don't know what version you're using. Boo hiss for wedging a whole bunch of JS into an `onclick`, btw, ignoring that it's not related to the issue.

Comment: I'm using Struts2.3.4. I realise var is depreciated. Had var, didn't work. Tried id as I had a post with a similar problem mentioned id worked along with # for the property value field. Can you let me know what further information would be necessary to help? Thank

Comment: Have you verified the array is being populated (via logging or debugging)? Have you verified the resulting DOM is valid? Have you verified the remainder of the page is being rendered with no errors? Have you verified no CSS/JS/etc. is either preventing or modifying list/list item/etc. display properties so it's invisible? There's a public `title` property available in DiaryEntry? (Ugh, "diaries" and "entries", and it's preferable to code to the `List` or `Collection` interface rather than a concrete implementation, and naming with `array` is misleading anyway since it's not an array.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will take your comments for better practices on board :)

Comment: Also, consider using `SessionAware` to clean up session variable access. Plurals (collections) should be named as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an obvious `ERROR` in your action class, you had `arrayDiary` and `arrayEvent` defined in your class and in your method `populate()`, there is for sure nothing happened in your `<s:iterator>`

please change your method `populate()` like this:

```
public String populate() {
    arrayEvent = new ArrayList<DiaryEntry>();
    arrayDiary = new ArrayList<DiaryEntry>();
    DiaryEntry load = new DiaryEntry();
    username = (String) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("username");
    loginId = (String) ActionContext.getContext().getSession().get("loginId");
    ArrayList<DiaryEntry> diaryEntry = load.loadDiaryEntry(username, loginId);
    for (DiaryEntry entry:diaryEntry) {
        if(entry.getEvent() == null) {
            arrayDiary.add(entry);
        }
        else {
            arrayEvent.add(entry);
        }
    }
    return "populate";
}
```

Comment: Good catch; totally missed it.